# AngularAdal restrict AD users

Tags: azure, adal, adal.js

I'm using AngularJS Adal plugin to handle login on my page, with Azure AD.
I got everything working and it's great, one problem I have is, I would like to restrict who in Azure AD can use the login, is this possible?

Thanks, 
Feeloor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restrict the users for the apps which protected by the Azure AD, we can config the app to enable the ‘User assignment required to access app’ on the portal like figure below:
[image]

Then we can assign/remove the users who you doesn’t want to use the app at the users tab like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD to manage access to resources such as your application. You can give specific users access or control access via groups where all members of a group are given access.

Here are some useful links to get you started

- [Managing access to resources with Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-managing-access-to-apps/)
- [Using a group to manage access](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-manage-groups/)